# Why does Moles keep getting readded to my project?

Tags: moles

I added Moles to a project in VS2010, decided I didn't want to use it and then removed the Moles reference and the .behaviours and .moles assemblies. The problem is that I repeatedly find Moles has been readded to the project with no intervention from me. Is there some kind of setting external to a project that will auto-add it if it's installed?

Comment: It seems that when the moled assembly changes (version change), Moles thinks that it needs to add it again ?

Answer (score 6):

Be sure you have done the following:

1. Remove the references to the moles assemblies (e.g. "MyAssembly.Moles")
2. Remove reference: Microsoft.Moles.Framework
3. Remove all .moles files (toggle the "Show all files" button in the solution explorer -- you must select the test class before doing so)
4. Delete the "Moled Assemblies" folder
5. Clean the test project (right-click the project in Solution Explorer, and then select Clean)
6. Rebuild the test project
7. Bask in the glory of a Moles-free test project

**UPDATE** (2 JULY 2012)
I recommend shifting to .NET 4.5 Fakes and Stubs (currently in Release Candidate version). Fakes and Stubs are the productized version of Moles, and are fully supported.

Comment: Great! Glad I can help.  I recommend shifting to Fakes and Stubs, in VS 2012 (currently in Release Candidate version). Fakes are the productized version of Moles, and is fully supported.